# Find a minimum of a quantity

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Let $n$ a positive integer. I have the following quantity:

$$Q = 3205 \cdot 3^{i-1} + 64i + 64i(3^{i-1}-1)-64(3^{i-1}-1)-32\times3^{i-1}(2i-5)+3$$

I would like to find the integer $i$ which minimizes $Q$, such that $Q \geq n-1$.

Can we give a formula for such $i$ in function of $n$? Is it computable?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $i$ an integer ? You should simplify the formula before trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, $i$ is an integer. I update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first thing I put your formula in WA and got [that](http://tinyurl.com/zbcanct). Sorry for the tinyurl link but WA links are not great because of the parenthesis. Also I replaced $i$ with $k$ to not confuse Him. Assuming I didn't make typo and He is right we have :
$$
3301\cdot3^{k-1}+67 \geq n-1 \\
3^{k-1} \geq \frac{n-68}{3301} \\
(k-1)log(3) \geq log(n-68) -log(3301) \\
k \geq \frac{log(n-68) -log(3301)}{log(3)} + 1
$$

Comment: Thanks Zubzub. My form was not simplified enough.